# What is this big Gold and Blue thing in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

I found something in Terraria and I want it, but I don't know what it's called. It looks gold and blue and I think you can get it from the celestial towers.

I tried asking the guide for help, I tried asking players for help, nothing.

What is it?

[image: Gold and Blue thing]

Comment: maybe you should add highlight to the item in question ?

Comment: Yes, it would be helpful if you could better point out the item on question

Answer (score 7):

I assume you are talking about the *Stardust Guardian* from [Stardust Armor](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Stardust_armor). That is obtained from crafting using Stardust Fragments obtained from the [Stardust Tower](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Celestial_Tower) with [Luminite Bar](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Luminite_Bar) from [Moonlord](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Moon_Lord) at the [Ancient Manipulator](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Ancient_Manipulator) obtained from the *Lunar Cultist* outside the *Dungeon* after [Golem](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Golem) is defeated.

Note: [Ancient Manipulator](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Ancient_Manipulator) is dropped by the single Boss-Level cultist that spawns after you killed those four chanting ones outside the *Dungeon*

Comment: @user179187 Mark the answer as accepted if it helped you.